# Elasticsearch indexing stops on certain index

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, elasticsearch

When I try indexing it by `bulk_indexing()` process it stops on certain index. I changed heap_size in `jvm.options` it doesn't help.

> This is the output:
>
> ```
> Product 489 indexed
> Product 490 indexed
> Product 491 indexed
> Product 492 indexed
> Product 493 indexed
> Product 494 indexed
> Product 495 indexed
> Product 496 indexed
> Product 497 indexed
> Product 498 indexed
> Product 2280 indexed
> POST http://localhost:9200/_bulk [status:N/A request:0.001s]
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "/code/products/documents.py", line 93, in bulk_indexing
>     bulk(client=es, actions=(p.indexing() for p in models.Product.objects.all().iterator()))
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 257, in bulk
>     for ok, item in streaming_bulk(client, actions, **kwargs):
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 192, in streaming_bulk
>     raise_on_error, **kwargs)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 99, in _process_bulk_chunk
>     raise e
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 95, in _process_bulk_chunk
>     resp = client.bulk('\n'.join(bulk_actions) + '\n', **kwargs)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 76, in _wrapped
>     return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 1150, in bulk
>     headers={'content-type': 'application/x-ndjson'})
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 314, in perform_request
>     status, headers_response, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, headers=headers, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 175, in perform_request
>     raise ConnectionError('N/A', str(e), e)
> elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ffb0733bb38>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ffb0733bb38>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
> ```

Comment: What is your actual question? [Edit] the question and tell us what you want to do, what you have tried, including a [mcve] and show the results. Format any errors and code so it is readable.

Comment: Format code always as `code`, outputs are better readable formated as code.

Comment: Where is your ES running? what is the size of the cluster and the client?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in chunk size . It was by default=500. I increased the size and it solved my problem